# Why do NPM node modules contain a bower.json file?

Tags: npm, bower

I've been tasked with removing bower where possible and instead using NPM to install modules. I've done a search of the codebase and the only bower.json files are within NPM node modules. I thought that NPM was an alternative to bower, is this incorrect?

I was expecting to find a bower.json file in the project root. As I haven't does it should like NPM is already being used instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NPM as an alternative to bower, yes.

Every module has a bower.json because the module wants to support bower and npm as well. Module managers can write stuff like version number, ignore certain files to download, etc. You don't need to worry about these files.

Your package doesn't have a bower.json - perfect. You don't support bower.